# When I try to install body parser with npm, I get npm does not support Node.js v9.2.0

Tags: node.js

Console error:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v9.2.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
WARNING: You are likely using a version of node-tar or npm that is incompatible with this version of Node.js.
Please use either the version of npm that is bundled with Node.js, or a version of npm (> 5.5.1 or < 5.4.0) or node-tar (> 4.0.1) that is compatible with Node.js 9 and above.
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe: src\node_zlib.cc:437: Assertion `args.Length() == 7 && "init(windowBits, level, memLevel, strategy, writeResult, writeCallback," " dictionary)"' failed.
```

Comment: Please format the error message. And please ask the proper question. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall previous version of Node as well as deleting %AppData%\npm and %AppData%\npm-cache. Then install Node 9.0.0 and you should be fine.

Warning: You will have to install all global packages again after doing npm cache clear.

Comment: deleting AppData\Roaming\npm and AppData\Roaming\npm-cache did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

The Version of npm you're using and the version of Node.js you're using are not paired together and the version of npm you've doesn't support it.

So what you can do, is either uninstall and reinstall node with npm or update npm like this:

```
npm i -g npm
```

this will update npm to the latest version :)